# Bounding boxes around text regions with different font size

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, ocr

I am trying to implement some kind of text detection algorithm and I want to separate the image into regions where each region contains different font size.

As in this image, for example:
[image: example]

Is there any easy way to implement it using python and/or opencv? if so, how?
I did tried googling it but could not find anything useful..
Thanks.

Comment: please read [ask]. As is, the answer is "yes". use google to find respective tutorials

Comment: I searched this problem but could not find anything...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an interesting question. There are a few steps that you need to take in order to achieve your goals. I hope you are sufficiently informed of basic computer vision algorithm (knowledge in openCV function helps) to understand the steps i am suggesting.

1. Group all the words together using morphological dilation process.
2. Use openCV findcountour function to label all the blobs. This will give you the width and height information of each blob as well.
3. Here is the tricky part, now that you have data on each blob, try to run a clustering algorithm on the data with the location(x,y) and geometry(width,height) as your features.
4. Once you cluster them correctly, its a matter of finding the leftmost, rightmost, topmost and bottom data to draw the bounding rect.

I hope this will provide you enough information to start you work. Its is not detailed but i think its enough to guide you.